# Does Windows 7 Home Premium support backing up to a network share

Tags: windows-7, backup, nas

Windows Vista Home Premium supports automated back ups to a network share, so I would assume the Windows 7 Home Premium would also have this feature. However, [several](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/compare) [pages](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore) on the Microsoft site make it not-so-clear to whether the feature made it into RTM.

Can anyone with Windows 7 Home Premium installed confirm whether or not you can set an automated backup to write files to a network drive? Failing that, can you trick it by using a network mapped drive?

*(I currently have the Ultimate RC installed and am trying to figure out which RTM version to by)*

Comment: a gazillion of decent backup programs - supported by any flavor of windows 7 - will do that, thus the answer is yes. however, if you're asking whether Windows 7 Home Premium natively features backup to network shares, you should rephrase your question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having just installed Home Premium onto a Virtual PC, I can confirm that not only does Home Premium **not** support backing up to a network share, but that mapped network drives do not show up in the "Backup Location" list.

Answer (score 0):

There's a page at Microsoft's website to [compare editions](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/compare/default.aspx) and it clearly states that only Professional and better has the backup to network feature.

It is my belief that Microsoft want you to buy a Windows Home Server to be able to backup over the network at home. If you already own a home server then you're good to go.

Comment: I linked to that page in my question. If you look at the link in Alex's answer, it implies the opposite. I have done research into this, I simply want someone with HP installed to confirm.

Comment: sorry about that, missed the link in your post.

Comment: No worries. I'd say you're probably right regarding Windows Home Server. Anyway, I'm installing HP (legit) onto VPC now so I'll see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offers a solution to this problem for free but will not tell you about it. It's called Sync Toy. It is a free application on their website in the download center. Here is the link.

> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52

It allows you to "sync" folders over your home network and even an external drive....

Comment: This is _not_ the same as its built-in backup. The built in backup tool can do full image backups; sync toy cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Szalay is completely correct in every account. However, there is a workaround that enables you to backup your Windows 7 Home Premium machine on to a network drive.

1. Right click on "My Computer" and hit "Manage".
2. Select "Disk Management"
3. Click on "Action" and select "Create VHD"

[image: Image of creating a VHD]

4. Set the location to be on the network
5. Choose a size large enough to store your backup
6. Right click on the words "Not Initialized" to initialize the disk

[image: Image of Initialize Disk]

7. Format the disk by right-clicking where it says "Unallocated" and select "New Simple Volume"

[image: Format disk]

This virtual disk will now show up in Backup and Restore!

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-do-backup-a-windows-7-machine-to-a-network/e733818b-0219-4037-b04d-166cff901dd7